# Debugging Content Security Policy violation in Google Chrome DEV

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-devtools, content-security-policy

I'm developing a Cordova Android application, and due to [Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/) restrictions, I often get several of this errors, some of which I know how to handle.

The question with Google Chrome Developing Tools, is that it simply mentions the error, without saying which part of the code triggers such error. The information is very vague.

[image: CSP violation]

How to know which part of the code triggered this error?

Comment: It says `inline event handler` meaning `onclick` or `onload` and so on. You can try divide-and-conquer debugging: remove half of the code and see if the error is gone, rinse and repeat recursively.

Comment: Actually it was something totally different, it was a miss string in an object such as `var obj = {'name': 'these dev tools don't work properly'};` which is really scary how this can occur and have so little feedback.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira the key part in the error is "unsafe-inline" -- this indicates the problem is an inline SCRIPT block which has to be allowed via  "unsafe-inline", or the script block needs a hash or nonce to indicate that particular inline script content is "safe"

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Sources' tab in dev tool, in the sidebar on the right, theres a pause button.
Clicking that will dropdown a checkbox saying 'Pause On Caught Exceptions'.
If you check that, the browser should stop execution at the point of exception.

If you have multiple exceptions on that site, you might have to press F8 in chrome dev a couple of times to get to the right error you're looking for.

[image: Chrome Dev tools]

Comment: it doesn't trigger that specific error regarding CSP

Comment: It doesn't trigger using pause on uncaught exceptions specifically because these are internal engine errors and not script execution errors. Therefore, there is nothing to pause on when a CSP error is thrown.